How can you calculate the distance to an object knowing its cosmological redshift? (without Hubbles law)
Given some redshift z, how do we find the distance using the cosmological red shift formula (and presumably the Friedmann equations)? a = 1/(1+z), and we can assume that omega_0 = 1. I know a reasonable answer can be achieved using Hubbles law, but was looking for the specific method going via a. Thank you! (all the necessary cosmological parameters can be assumed to be known..)

Which distance are you talking about? The luminosity distance, angular-diameter distance, co-moving distance, or proper distance?

There are different concepts of distance, which all obtain the same measure in a non-expanding flat space, i.e. in everyday live and the local universe, but differ in an expanding universe. The luminosity distance $D_L$ is defined as that inferred from the apparent brightness of a source with known absolute brightness, while the angular-diameter distance $D_A$ is defined as that inferred from the angular size of an object with known physical size. In addition, there is the co-moving distance (reception distance) $D_c$ and proper distance $D_p$ (emission distance in the figure below).

The co-moving or reception distance can be computed from
$$
D_c = \int\mathrm{d} x = \int_{t(z)}^{t_0}\frac{c\mathrm{d}t}{a(t)} = \int_0^z\frac{c\mathrm{d}z}{H(z)}
$$
where (from the Friedman equation)
$$
H^2(z) = H_0^2 \left[\Omega_{\mathrm{r}}(1+z)^4 + \Omega_{\mathrm{m}}(1+z)^3 + \Omega_\kappa(1+z)^2 + \Omega_\Lambda\right].
$$
Here $\Omega_{\mathrm{r}}$, $\Omega_{\mathrm{m}}$, $\Omega_\Lambda$ are the density parameters for radiation, matter, and dark energy, while $\Omega_\kappa=1-\Omega_{\mathrm{r}}-\Omega_{\mathrm{m}}-\Omega_\Lambda$ is the curvature term. The currently favoured cosmology has $\Omega_{\mathrm{r}}=8.4\cdot10^{-5}$, $\Omega_{\mathrm{m}}=0.309$, $\Omega_\Lambda=0.691$, $\Omega_\kappa=0$, and $H_0=67.7\,$km/s/Mpc (see here).
The proper or emission distance $D_p$ follows from
$$
D_p = a(t) D_c = \frac{D_c}{1+z}
$$
and for a flat universe (as ours seems to be, since $\Omega_\kappa=0$) $D_A=D_p$, while
$$
D_L = (1+z)^2D_A
$$
in any case. Note that $D_p(z)$ is non-monotonic: the angular-diameter distance becomes maximal for some redshift. For the currently favoured cosmology, this occurs for $z\approx1.5$ with $D_{A,\max} \approx 0.4 c/H_0 \sim 10^{13}$pc ('maximum distance of lightcone' in the figure). Objects at yet larger redshift appear larger and hence at smaller $D_A$.
